# Error installing pip package on debian / python 3.4

Tags: python, debian, pip, python-3.4

I have python 3.4 compiled from sources on my debian 7.8.
I have already installed some Python packages using `pip` and `virtualenv` (django, pillow etc), but i have an error installing `python-phonenumbers` (https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers).
I tried it using virtualenv and without, running pip3 install phonenumbers and manually downloading archive and running `python3 setup.py install`. Every time I get same error:

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ogsbxm_d/phonenumbers/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)
.read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))"
install --record /tmp/pip-98gunm55-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile"
failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-build-ogsbxm_d/phonenumbers
```

I tried it on my windows and ubuntu 14.04 - everything ok. How can i fix it?

Comment: What's in  /tmp/pip-build-ogsbxm_d/phonenumbers?

Comment: it is deleted before i can view it

Answer (score 1):

For `Ubuntu 14.04`, from Docker image `python:3.4.3-slim` this combination worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev

pip3 install psycopg2
```

Note `build-essential` package. It was crucial in my case. Maybe it will help you too.